# Inter Quake Model IQM render Directx9

Tags: opengl, rendering, blender, directx9

I'm trying to render an Inter Quake Model(http://lee.fov120.com/iqm/) in DirectX9 that I exported from blender.

I want to display animations which IQM supports and my model format does not.

The model is a cylinder.

It loads fine in the iqm sdk opengl viewer but when i try to render it in directx9 using for example(this is just to render the vertices):

```
IDirect3DDevice9 * device;
HRESULT hr = S_OK;


for(int i = 0; i < nummeshes; i++)
{
    iqmmesh &m = meshes[0];


    hr = device->DrawIndexedPrimitiveUP(D3DPT_TRIANGLELIST, 0,
    3*m.num_triangles, m.num_triangles ,&tris[m.first_triangle] ,D3DFMT_INDEX32 
    ,inposition ,sizeof(unsigned int));
}
```

It renders like this:

[Incorrect](http://i1339.photobucket.com/albums/o707/_Andrew0/IQMAnimation.jpg)

The light grey bit that looks like two triangles in the middle is what is rendered(ignore the other stuff).

Whereas it is meant to look like this(using a custom importer which I designed which matches what is displayed in blender):

[Correct](http://i1339.photobucket.com/albums/o707/_Andrew0/CorrectIQM.jpg)

Anyone have any suggestions on what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last parameter of your DIP call is wrong - it should be the size of your vertex struct, which - for position only - is going to be 3 floats.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Can't believe I missed that... I'd vote your answer up but won't let me without 15 rep...